# How to avoid hardcoded url in Django view in that case?

Tags: python, django

I know we usually reverse(someview) to avoid hardcoded urls in views.

But in my case:

```
@user_passes_test(is_logged_owner, login_url=reverse(signin_owner))
def view_1(request):
    # stuff...

def signin_owner(request):
    # stuff...
```

This does not work, this raises an ImproperlyConfigured error at any URL (message is : The included urlconf hellodjango.urls doesn't have any patterns in it).

I have no idea of what's happening since views seems to be well defined in urls.py (and I never had mistakes like this in 6 months).

root urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^', include('myapp.urls')),
)
```

myapp urls.py (part of it):

```
url(r'^signin_owner$', views.signin_owner, name='signin_owner'),
```

Thanks!

Comment: your project name is `hellodjango` ?

Comment: Oh, I tought you copied the example django project and forgot to change the name. Can you paste your `urls.py` ? and where is defined your `view_2`

Comment: That could be this but I have doubts since I work on this project for 6 months and never had mistakes like this before. I updated the code. Thanks.

Comment: did you try to define signin_owner before view_1?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking of this too. But same result :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your are using URL reversal before your URLconf is loaded due to which `reverse` wouldn't work. The solution to this is using [reverse_lazy](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) instead.

Now your view will be something like this:

```
@user_passes_test(is_logged_owner, login_url=reverse_lazy('signin_owner',))
def view_1(request):
    # stuff...
```

Comment: Excellent!!! That's it, thank you. I didn't know that it could be required in urls inside decorators.